# Generic difference between two method expression

Tags: java, generics

What is the difference between the following two type of method declaration?

```
public static Type[] someMethod(Type[] type ){
}

public static <Type> someMethod(Type[] type ){
}
```

Comment: One stands a better chance of compiling and has a return type of `Type[]`; the other doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

The second form does not define a return type. Also, follow the Java naming conventions. A type parameter name should be a single uppercase letter.